# drupal commerce customization

Tags: commerce, rules, users, datetime

I'm trying to build a site for registering educational classes...(sell them)

I want to use Drupal commerce, and add some properties like time,teacher etc. but I want to add some things:

every class has specific capacity. I want users to first, register, then if someone wanted to register, register something like reserved...meanwhile,if sb cancelled order, the reserved people would be registered, after all, we approve the people, no matter registered or reserved, then they can pay....

another thing is that I want that products expire after a while, for example until the tomorrow registration(buying) is allowed.

Is it possible to do these with commerce or Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the first part. About the expiring date you can use [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler).

You can decide when you want to unpublish or publish some content (Product display in your case).

Comment: for example class 1 has the capacity of 50. I want, if the 51st person came, register as "reserved" or sth like that.

Comment: and users should be able to delete their classes, and reserved people become registered. and another thing after a while that they decided to delete or not, we allow them to pay... I really thank you for your help :)

Comment: Oh... in that case you should work around http://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock. It gives you the change to add the quantity to a product. Then you could try using rules or modifing the module to get the result you want.